# Android SDK Manager download finished with wrong checksum?

Tags: android-sdk-tools

I am using Android SDK Manager revision 23.0.5. I tried to update some SDK, but got this errors. I tried a lot of times. And I try to use "https://" in the option but failed. I have this trouble all day. How can I fix it?
[image: Android sdk manager error]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry for this question, finally I find it's the network problem between Google and me. China has blocked Google. After I had used VPN, everything is OK. Thank you all for your help.

So I suggest you to check the connection between you and Google. Make sure everything is OK. Then you still have the error, you can try @Alireza Kazemi and @Hirak Chhatbar's solution.

Answer (score 12):

Clearing the SDK Manager cache: [Tools > Options > Clear] Cache and the reloading [Package > Reload] helps.

Also in some cases disabling the real time protection of your anti virus or the whole anti virus may solve the problem.

Finally a guess may be that forcing to use http for downloading repos may solve some problems [Tools > Options > Force https sources to be downloaded using http].

Comment: For those who can't find the Tools ,Go to Sdk manager ,In Sdk manager status bar you will find the Tools "NOTE: Don't go to android studio Tools". I disabled the Tools=>Options=>Force https sources to be downloaded using http , And it worked for me !!!!

Comment: I no longer see the option to clear cache in my SDK manager 25.2.5 on Mac

Answer (score 7):

go to tools ---> Options ---> Clear Cache. Then Packages ---> Reload

Answer (score 1):

To facilitate finding the clear cache on SDK Manager:

For SDK Manager 25.2.5 on Mac, select SDK Manager -> Preferences or press `Command + ,`

And there is the button to `Clear Cache`

[image: SDK Manager preferences]

However, I still cannot resolve my checksum error.

---

**UPDATE:**

The comment by @ded to this answer posts the link to the solution which worked for me.

Comment: None of the above fixed my checksum error. I solved the problem by downloading manually (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/47005171)