# Error installing SDK through sdkmanager in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

I was trying to install GPU Debugging tool from the sdkmanager of Android Studio. But the following error came:

```
Packages to install: 
- GPU Debugging tools (extras;android;gapid;3)

Preparing "Install GPU Debugging tools (revision: 3.1.0)".
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/gapid_2994895_linux.zip
This download could not be finalized from the interim state. Retrying without caching.
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/gapid_2994895_linux.zip
Failed packages:
- GPU Debugging tools (extras;android;gapid;3)
```

This was the log.

```
2020-05-04 15:26:06,959 [  35766]   WARN - ls.idea.sdk.wizard.InstallTask - Checksum of the downloaded result didn't match the expected value. 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Checksum of the downloaded result didn't match the expected value.
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.StudioDownloader.lambda$doDownloadFully$2(StudioDownloader.java:216)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests.doProcess(HttpRequests.java:537)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests.process(HttpRequests.java:513)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests.access$100(HttpRequests.java:61)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests$RequestBuilderImpl.connect(HttpRequests.java:363)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.StudioDownloader.doDownloadFully(StudioDownloader.java:193)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.StudioDownloader.lambda$doDownloadFully$2(StudioDownloader.java:223)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests.doProcess(HttpRequests.java:537)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests.process(HttpRequests.java:513)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests.access$100(HttpRequests.java:61)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests$RequestBuilderImpl.connect(HttpRequests.java:363)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.StudioDownloader.doDownloadFully(StudioDownloader.java:193)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.StudioDownloader.downloadFullyWithCaching(StudioDownloader.java:140)
    at com.android.repository.impl.installer.BasicInstaller.doPrepare(BasicInstaller.java:71)
    at com.android.repository.impl.installer.AbstractPackageOperation.prepare(AbstractPackageOperation.java:337)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.wizard.InstallTask.preparePackages(InstallTask.java:253)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.wizard.InstallTask.run(InstallTask.java:120)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:894)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:169)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:591)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:537)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:156)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$4.run(CoreProgressManager.java:408)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2020-05-04 15:26:06,960 [  35767]   INFO - ectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger - Failed packages: 
2020-05-04 15:26:06,960 [  35767]   INFO - ectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger - - GPU Debugging tools (extras;android;gapid;3)
```

On searching the internet I came through this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26499617/android-sdk-manager-download-finished-with-wrong-checksum). But There is no tools option in sdkmanager window.

My System:
Android Studio 3.6.3
Xubuntu 20.04
JDK version 11

Comment: Same here. Retried a lot.
```
Packages to install: 
- Google X86_ARM Intel x86 Atom System Image (system-images;android-28;google_ndk;x86)

Preparing "Install Google X86_ARM Intel x86 Atom System Image (revision: 10)".
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/x86-28_r10.zip
This download could not be finalized from the interim state. Retrying without caching.
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/x86-28_r10.zip
Failed packages:
- Google X86_ARM Intel x86 Atom System Image (system-images;android-28;google_ndk;x86)
```

Answer (score 12):

This was the error I was getting while following instructions for react native at https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.

[image: Error while setting up Android Studio for React native]

This is what I did to resolve it.

- Downloaded the [x86_64-31_r03.zip](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android/x86_64-31_r03.zip) manually from the browser
- Create a dir called `intel` in `c:\users\<username>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-31\`
- Extracted the content of the zip file into `intel`
- Restarted Android Studios

Comment: And for Mac, the path was "/Users/<username>/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-31/default". I had to remove the existing x86_64 directory at that path first (it contained a suspicious .installer directory).

Comment: Excellent. This worked perfectly on Windows 10.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to manually download the zip file and extract it to the SDK dir so the resulting path looked like this:

```
android-sdk/system-images/android-28/google_apis/x86
```

AVD detected the image afterwards.

Another example path:

```
android-sdk/system-images/android-30/google_apis_playstore/x86_64
```

Answer (score 5):

after a lot of research and trying I'm sharing what solved the problem on my MacOS 12.4

**1º - Directly download NDK r21 package (or whatever you want):**

Run the code in the terminal to download the package:

```
wget -c https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r21-darwin-aarch64.zip
```

**2º - Unzip the downloaded file by running the code below:**

```
unzip android-ndk-r21-darwin-aarch64.zip -d x86_64
```

The file will be in the following path: /Users/${NAME-YOUR-PC}/x86_64

**3º - Copy all the files that are inside the `android-ndk-r21` folder (it will be inside the x86_64 folder)**

**4º - Paste into the folder: `/Users/${NAME-YOUR-PC}/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/21.0.6113669` the copied files.**

**5º - Try to run the APP one more time.**

Answer (score 1):

I am download and manually install success in macOS, first download the zip:

```
wget -c https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r21-darwin-aarch64.zip
```

then unzip the file:

```
unzip android-ndk-r21-darwin-aarch64.zip -d ${VERSION_FOLDER}
```

replace the file name which you want to download.