# Install sdk component intel x86 atom_64 System image but it always fails and is giving the following error

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, development-environment

Its almost 10th time that I am trying to install sdk component intel x86 atom_64 System image but it always fails and is giving the following error

[image: this is the error it shows when I install it]

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/61589907/150978

Answer (score 0):

1. First can manually download the zip file from the official system Image [repository](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android/x86_64-31_r03.zip)
2. Secondly extract the contents of zip folder into the `SDK` folder in your machine. Generally it is found here:

```
c:\users\<yourusername>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-<api#>\
```

In case it is not present, you can create a directory named `google_apis` inside `c:\users\<yourusername>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-<api#>\`

Once you do that, then open AS, AVD will automatically detect the image.

Comment: how to download manually

Comment: C:\Users\{Your UserName}\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-30\google_apis\x86

Comment: i have downloaded the zip file and copied it in google_apis-x86 fo;der but on android stuion when i open sdk platform it still  shows not istalled

Comment: Apologies for delay, due to difference in timezone. I have edited the answer, I hope it helps.

Comment: i have downloaded the folder but when i open AS tha Sdk manger , in the sdk components it shows that intel x86 system image is not installed